# Vim: quickly returning to a part of the text

Tags: vim

I have been trying to learn Vim and have been using it for 2 weeks now.

My question is how do I return the cursor immediately to the middle of the text I just typed:

I have a tendency to type:

```
<div>
</div>
```

and returning back to the content of the tag and writing its contents:

```
<div>
text
</div>
```

This also goes for functions:

```
function eat() {
}
```

before getting back to the middle of the and typing it's contents:

```
function eat(){
  blah
}
```

Comment: You can use [snippets](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2540).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

An uppercase `O`, so <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>o</kbd>, inserts an empty line above the one you're currently on and puts you into insert mode where you can begin typing. It was kind of an epiphany for me when I first figured that out.

Comment: Moreover, most normal mode commands have some neat "augmented" or in some sense "reverted" usage in upper case.

Answer (score 2):

If you work a lot with html / xml tags, have a look at [surround.vim](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1697)

Answer (score 0):

I agree with michaelmichael, `O` works in both of your examples above.

In general, in vi or vim, you can use "macro" to achieve this. This feature acts like a bookmark, despite its name.

`ma` will define a macro called 'a'.
`` `a `` will take you back to where the bookmark was defined. If you want the beginning of the line, use `'a`

So, if you typed 'ma' at the appropriate spot, continued typing, then typed '`a', it would achieve the effect you're looking for.

Comment: The term "macro" refers to a sequence of actions that have been recorded by pressing 'q'. The correct term for what you are talking about is a "mark".

Answer (score 0):

- Snipmate plugin - [Completion codes
  dynamics](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2540)
- [see an example of plugin in action at the vimeo site](http://vimeo.com/3535418)